# Drag Drop On The Edge Of A Shape With react-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I need ideas to develop drag-drop an arrow on the edge of a geometric shape like a rectangle, circle, etc in a React project that uses react-dnd for showing north direction. On the other hand, I should save the arrow's location to show it again in the same place. Any ideas?

[image: Rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to save the coordinates somewhere in your state. Then use `useDrop` hook ([doc](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop)) to push the new coordinates of the arrow to your state when it's dropped to a new position.

To sum up, the process is the following:

- init your coordinates in the state  to where you want the arrow to be
- make your arrow component draggable using `useDrag`

  - pass to `useDrag` a `begin` callback -that modifies your state- which will be called whenever the arrow starts to be dragged
  - do the same with the `end` callback
  - then it will be animated and you will be able to drag it, it will follow, you can even change its appearance based on the state item you set in your `begin` and `end` functions
- make your arrow component droppable using `useDrop`

  - as for `useDrag`, pass a `drop` function to push to state the new coordinates of the arrow.

It's a bit hard to help you more than this as you don't provide any code. If the reason for this is that you don't know where to start from, please have a look to this amazing [step-by-step tutorial](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/tutorial).

However, keep in mind all this triggers a lot of re-renders. Personally, for this king of stuff, I like to avoid using third-party libs, to keep performance under control, and tend to stick the closest possible to the dom (using js events instead of continuously updating the state when dragging for instance) .

Comment: Thank you @bonjour123 for ur interest, but my main problem is making only shape's lines drag-dropable. Did you explain it in here?

Comment: You mean that you want it to stick (when dropped) only on the line ? If so, you just need to check in the drop function if the current position is over a line or not. If yes, then set new position to state, else, discard and do nothing.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Discarding is bad for user experience. Drag shouldnt work outside of line.

Comment: Well, I guess you could compute the closest coordinates on the line, and put it to the state inside the canDrag function. But honestly, do it with plain vanilla js, it's going to be a lot faster, and effective code, while also a lot easier for you. On mouseUp, update you state to keep the new position, and that's all

Comment: I suggest you to use the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648937/5499697) and make the little modifications needed.